# Using MERN Stack on web app and want to display html post with a creation time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose-schema, mern

Currently running the following code within MERN stack. Intended to display posts (when a '/get 'request is passed). I am required to add features. My current challenge is displaying a createdAt (or similar) timestamp alongside my Post.  I  have the following line added to my schema

```
  message: { type: String, required: true },
  //date: { type: Date, required: true },
  time: { type: Date, default: Date:  },
});
```

I want to use the 'time:' document, to extract time the post was created, and display the time alongside the Post

```
import React from "react";
import formatDistanceToNow from "date-fns/formatDistanceToNow";

const Post = ({ post }) => {
  const formattedDate = formatDistanceToNow(new Date(), {
    addSuffix: true
  });
  return (
    <article data-cy="post" key={post._id}>
      {post.message}
      Published {formattedDate}
    </article>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

response (among many errors) - `Published Less than a minute ago`

Used postman to create posts and tableplus (and compass) to check my schema. I noticed that after adding  'time:' into my schema document it hasn't become visible on these databases.   At this point I'd be happy to return simply dateNow/CreatedAt data, and not necessarily the DistanceToNow time calculation. (A CreatedAt (or similar) func would be most useful!)  I have tried all the above in some form or other but broken the prog or return a inexplicable times! Please excuse any major faux-pas in the 'lingusitics'. Im relatively new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

there are some ways to create default date:

```
time: { type: Date, default: Date.now  }, //timestamp
```

or

```
time: { type: Date, default: new Date()  }, //date Object
```

and MongoDb it self has provided ISODate,

```
time: { type: Date, default: new ISODate()  }, // timestamp
```

Comment: Thanks for your response- I have come across these commands on the mongodb page - I  previously copied them first into my usersSchema / but I haven’t been able to determine how to  implement them from my posts.js file. The timestamp command logged as undefined in the dev console . I haven’t come across ‘iso date’  so will explore when I return to my machine. Given my code block above -how should i call the ‘iso date’on the html? Many thanks for your time

Comment: if you put it in your schema, it should be automatically inserted.

Comment: and if you want to add it manually, you can deconstruct the variable post in post.js to be like `const newPost = {time: new Date(), ...post}`

Comment: Amazing- thank you. I look forward to trying that in the morning and will sleep better knowing I have a plan!! Best wishes.